# Netflix Custom Wine usable with other programs?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, netflix

I noticed that the WINE installed to run the Netflix app found [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/how-to-get-netflix-streaming-on-ubuntu-1210/4019) installs a custom WINE along with the full Mono and possibly .NET .  I have been having chronic problems getting the program Reply Media Catcher to work on Wine 1.4 and 1.5.19, using both plain WINE and PlayOnLinux; will this version of WINE due to it's tighter integration of .NET possibly make using Windows programs in general easier to install, or is it too focused to be used as a general WINE?